# Classifying space $\text{BU}(n)$ from the differential-geometric point of view?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, classifying-spaces

The classifying space of a topological group $G$ is the quotient of $EG$ (a topological space with vanishing homotopy groups) by a proper free action of $G$. The standard notation for the classifying space of $G$ is $BG$, with $B$ short for "*classifying space*".

The classifying space of the unitary group $\text{U}(n)$ is $\text{BU}(n) \simeq \text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$, where $\text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$ is the "inductive-limit" of the embeddings $$\text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}^k) \hookrightarrow \text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}^{k+1}) \hookrightarrow \cdots.$$

The infinite Grassmannian $\text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$ is not finite-dimensional, and is therefore not a manifold in the usual sense.

> Are there any results concerning the differential-geometric structure of $\text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$?

> Can we speak of the curvature of $\text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$? Do we know anything about the curvature of "Riemannian metrics" which reside on $\text{Gr}_n(\mathbb{C}^{\infty})$?

Comment: $U(H)$ (unitary group of a Separable Hilbert space) is a pretty 
nice  contractible Frechet manifold. As a subgroup, $U(n)$ acts freely on it, so  quotient would be my first candidate for a differential-geometric model of BU(n)

Comment: The title asks a slightly different question than the actual post.  A “better” classifying object for the unitary group is the classifying stack B(U(n)), and it is certainly possible to talk about the differential geometry of B(U(n)).  For example, Freed and Hopkins in “Chern–Weil forms and abstract homotopy theory” compute the de Rham complex of B(U(n)), which turns out to be precisely isomorphic (and not just quasi-isomorphic) to the algebra of Chern classes.

Comment: You might find this paper interesting: https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5959 ("Chern-Weil forms and abstract homotopy theory", by Dan Freed and Mike Hopkins)

Answer (score 7):

In Example 1.2.22 of [Nicolaescu - Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/Lectures.pdf)  you will find a description of the manifold structure  of $\DeclareMathOperator{\Gr}{Gr}\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}$$\Gr_n(V)$,  where $V$ is a finite dimensional complex Hilbert space. The finite dimensionality is used only in computing the dimension.  It is described  as a submanifold in the real  Hilbert space of (bounded) self-adjoint operators  $V\to V$.  As such it has  an induced metric.

If  you  fix a  orthonormal basis $(e_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of $V$, then you can produce  a stratification of $\Gr_k(V)$ by Schubert cells   of finite codimension. One can show that these define cohomology classes spanning the cohomology  of $\Gr_k(V)$;   Appendix A of [Localization formulae in odd K-theory by Daniel  Cibotaru](https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.2563)    explains how one can  associate cohomology classes to strata under certain conditions that are satisfied in this case.

These strata also have a Morse theoretic description.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, these are very nice notes! Does this give a "curvature" description of the classifying space? I put curvature in "..." since I'm not sure how one makes sense of the curvature of an infinite-dimensional manifold. Essentially, I want to know whether the classifying space is positively or negatively curved (in any sense of the word).

Comment: I don't know how to define Ricci or scalar curvature since they involve infinite summations.

Comment: MathJax warning: `$\DeclareMathOperator{\Gr}{Gr}$ $\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}$ $\Gr_n(V)$` would be fine TeX, but, in MathJax, forces unwanted spaces. As ugly as it is, you must remove all spaces:  `$\DeclareMathOperator{\Gr}{Gr}\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}$$\Gr_n(V)$`.  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

One prerequisite to any differential-geometric point of view of course is that $G$ is a Lie group rather than just a topological group.

Then, one option is to pass from manifolds to Lie groupoids:

- If $G$ is a Lie group, then there is a Lie groupoid with one object whose automorphism group is $G$; let's denote this Lie groupoid by $BG$.
- If $M$ is a smooth manifold, then there is a Lie groupoid with objects $M$ and only identity morphisms. Let's denote this Lie groupoid by $M$ again.

"The correct" kind of morphisms between Lie groupoids are "smooth anafunctors" a.k.a. "principal bibundles". All smooth anafunctors between two Lie groupoids from a category (Lie groupoids become a bicategory when equipped with such morphisms).

There is a canonical equivalence of categories:
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(M,BG) \cong \operatorname{Bun}_G(M).
$$
This is the Lie-groupoidal version for the classification of $G$-bundles by morphisms to a fixed object, $BG$. Note that everything takes places in finite-dimensional smooth manifolds, and it works for any Lie group $G$.

The relation to the classical picture is established by geometric realization (of topological groupoids). For example, $\lvert BG\rvert$ is a model for the classifying space, and smooth anafunctors induce homotopy classes of continuous maps.

This pov is explained in Section 2 of:

*Nikolaus, Thomas; Waldorf, Konrad*, [**Four equivalent versions of nonabelian gerbes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.2013.264.355), Pac. J. Math. 264, No. 2, 355-420 (2013). [ZBL1286.55006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1286.55006).